# Google Chrome: A wildcard '*' cannot be used in the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header when the credentials flag is true

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome, xmlhttprequest, accesscontrolexception

I know this is something usual, With the earlier versions of chrome I used to set "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --args --disable-web-security --user-data-dir  in chrome shortcut tab to avoid 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'  errors. With the latest version, it seems like this fix is not working anymore. After installing the latest version 53.0.2785.89 m this is the error in console

XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://example.org:15003/apps/services/preview/rr/common/1.0/default/index.html. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: A wildcard '*' cannot be used in the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header when the credentials flag is true. Origin 'http://ibm-pb7en65:10080' is therefore not allowed access. The credentials mode of an XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.

I am not sure which additional attributes are to be added to avoid 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' error.Is there any way this can be achieved?

Comment: *"With the latest version, it seems like this fix is not working anymore."* It's not a fix, it's a flag you'd only use in development. Hopefully you haven't been surfing the web with security disabled like that!

Comment: `which additional attributes are to be added` - additional to what? you've not shown any code at all, so are we supposed to guess what you're currently doing?

Comment: --args --disable-web-security --user-data-dir  flags are set currently do I need to add anyother flags ?

Answer (score 9):

The error is telling you that the server sent back this response header:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

...on a *credentialed* request. That doesn't work. On a request with credentials, the server must return a *specific* `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header.

Since you're making the request from `http://ibm-pb7en65:10080/`, your server must send back this header:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://ibm-pb7en65:10080
```

It cannot use the wildcard `*` instead.

The solution is either:

- Update the server to do that, or
- Remove credentials from the request

Details, as always, [in the specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/access-control/).

Comment: Hi Crowder, Thanks for the reply.

Comment: I am supposed to not to update server.I am using angular $http get call and by default withCredentials attribute is set to true by angular if I am not wrong. Is there any other way to fix this. To remind you same code worked earlier with older version of chrome.

Comment: I managed to solve this by this flag --user-data-dir="C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\AppData\Local\Temp"

Comment: Had the same using Chrome while `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` was in fact NOT a wildcard.

Worked perfectly in Firefox.

Only when I removed `withCredentials = true` did the error go away.