# Read/Write Error with Cloud Firestore: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'null'

Tags: javascript, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I have a Javascript Web application. I trying to read or write to the Cloud Firestore database but it returns this error in the browser console.

**THE ERROR:**

> Failed to load https://firestore.googleapis.com/google.firestore.v1beta1.Firestore/Write/channel?VER=8&RID=21505&CVER=21&X-HTTP-Session-Id=gsessionid&%24httpHeaders=X-Goog-Api-Client%3Agl-js%2F%20fire%2F4.8.2%0D%0Agoogle-cloud-resource-prefix%3Aprojects%2FProjectName%2Fdatabases%2F(default)%0D%0A&zx=v9xcdtq156tr&t=1:
>       The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'null' that is not equal to the supplied origin. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

The Security Rules were set to **Public read/write**

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
   match /{document=**} {
     allow read, write;
   }
 }
}
```

Here is my test code

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.11.0/firebase.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.11.0/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
<script>
  var config = {
    apiKey: "XXXXXXXXXXX",
    authDomain: "XXXXXXXXXXXX",
    databaseURL: "XXXXXXXXXXXX",
    projectId: "XXXXXXXXXXXX",
    storageBucket: "XXXXXXXXXXXX",
    messagingSenderId: "XXXXXXXXXXXX"
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);

  // Firebase Variables
  var db = firebase.firestore();

  db.collection("cities").doc("LA").set({
    name: "Los Angeles",
    state: "CA",
    country: "USA"
  }).then(function () {
    console.log("Document successfully written!");
  }).catch(function (error) {
    console.error("Error writing document: ", error);
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 9):

Google Chrome Version 65.0.3325.162 is the problem.
Tested with Microsoft Edge and it worked

Comment: If you are experiencing the same problem, use other web browsers or downgrade to Chrome 64.
Fixing the problem with code, NO SOLUTION.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39286997 for the general problem and how it is supposed to be solved.

Comment: That works to @ThomasAhle or test on local servers like WampServer and others

Comment: I was getting the same error with using the site http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com. I updated Chrome 65 to Chrome 66 and it is no longer an issue.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the CORS error it seems to be you are running the test code without using any kind of development server (e.g. [Nodemon][1], [webpack-dev-server][2] or [SimpleHTTPServer][3]). In the past, I also got the similar error when open the index.html file directly using a browser without any HTTP server.

If you have python installed on your computer, try to run the HTTP server inside the directory where it contains the index HTML file.

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000
```