# How to use Laravel and Nuxtjs with Authentication, including login, logout, and password resets?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, nuxt.js, laravel-8

I can't find any resource to help with this issue, there are some repos that provide some type of base, but not many of them actually work.

**Goals**: Run Laravel has the backend API, run NuxtJS as the frontend SPA, either 2 separate locations or combined into one.

Needs to have proper authentication between both systems for logging in users. [Laravel Sanctum](https://github.com/laravel/sanctum) looks to solve some of the SPA issues, but its hard to find proper documentation that actually shows a fully setup example.

1. Tested this idea https://github.com/zondycz/laravel-nuxt-sanctum But has failed, doesnt work with npm, must use yarn, however, login errors, doesnt work out of box. Repo needs work.
2. This tutorial [Secure authentication in Nuxt SPA with Laravel as back-end](https://dev.to/stefant123/secure-authentication-in-nuxt-spa-with-laravel-as-back-end-19a9) was very indepth, and looked promising, however, refresh tokens don't seem to work with the SPA side since the author developed it on static nuxt. Though I feel like it could be modified to work, I havent found the solution yet.
3. This template, [Laranuxt](https://github.com/m2sd/LaraNuxt) looked very promising, though I've yet to try it, im not sure if they are regularly updating it at this point, which was previously built by [Laravel Nuxt JS](https://github.com/skyrpex/laravel-nuxt-js) (abandoned project)

I was able to run the #2, while refresh tokens dont exactly work, I can still authenticate the user, but now the other issue is password resets, which I'm unable to properly setup through the nuxt form.

Has anyone found resources or solved this issue with communication between these frameworks? or am I going done a rabbit hole that seems to have no end in sight?

I guess another way could be saying, can you do a fully restful authentication system?

Hopefully this isn't too broad of a topic, looking for some guidance on this issue as its hard to find proper tutorials or documentation without writing too much core code myself.

Comment: I wrote an answer about setting up a Vue/Nuxt SPA with a Laravel backend [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63200511/how-to-retrieve-laravel-csrf-token-using-separated-vue-frontend/63201361#63201361). Maybe it'll help guide you in the right direction!

Comment: @FullStackOfPancakes Thanks this gives me something to see. I already have it running a get for `/sanctum/csrf-cookie` and a post login after, but when the login happens, laravel says `CSRF token mismatch.` for some reason, something isnt connecting the dots.

Answer (score 10):

It seems many people struggle to implement Sanctum for SPA authentication when splitting the front and back across separate domains, and the problem is usually CORS related. The Sanctum documentation is great, but assumes a knowledge of CORS (or assumes requests will be same-origin). I'll break down the setup as I see it, providing a little extra support where I feel the docs fall short. A long answer, but towards the end I **will** address your question which seems to focus specifically on authentication.

**Taken from Sanctum documentation:**

*First, you should configure which **domains** your SPA will be making requests from.*

Assuming your front-end app lives at https://www.my-awesome-app.io, what is the **domain**? What about http://localhost:3000? Domains map to IP addresses, not protocols or port numbers. So the domains in the given examples would be *[www.my-awesome-app.io](http://www.my-awesome-app.io)* and *localhost*. With that in mind, all you need to do at this stage is go to the `sanctum.php` file in your config directory and set the value of the `'stateful'` key to match the domain your Laravel API will *receive* requests from. **Although domain names by definition do not include port numbers, the Sanctum docs make it very clear this is also required if you're accessing via a URL that requires a specific port.**

```
/config/sanctum.php
...
'stateful' => [
    'localhost:3000',
],
```

or

```
'stateful' => [
    'my-awesome-app.io',
],
```

.env files are useful here.

*If you are having trouble authenticating with your application from an SPA that executes on a separate subdomain, you have likely misconfigured your CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) or session cookie settings.*

Indeed. So what does a correct setup look like? Assuming a recent Laravel version using the fruitcake/laravel-cors package, you will have a cors.php file in your /config folder. The default looks like:

**Default**

```
/config/cors.php
...
'paths' => ['api/*'],
'allowed_methods' => ['*'],
'allowed_origins' => ['*'],
'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],
'allowed_headers' => ['*'],
'exposed_headers' => [],
'max_age' => 0,
'supports_credentials' => false,
```

We have some work to do here. First, the `paths`. At the moment, our Laravel API is set up to allow requests from *any* external origin **only if they are trying to access the /api/* routes**. This can lead to trouble early on when, as the Sanctum docs require, we try to access a csrf cookie from the path `/sanctum/csrf-cookie`. Requests to this path are not explicitly permitted in our cors.php file, so they will fail. To fix, we could do this:

```
'paths' => [
    'api/*',
    'sanctum/csrf-cookie'
]
```

and now requests to /sanctum/csrf-cookie will be permitted. As a sidenote, I find it personally very useful to change the prefix from `sanctum` to `api`, that way I can set a single base url for my http client (usually axios).

```
import axios from 'axios';

axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
axios.defaults.baseURL = 'http://localhost:3000/api';
```

To change the path, you can change the following in the /config/sanctum.php file:

```
'prefix' => 'api',
```

Now GET requests to /api/csrf-cookie will return the cookie, instead of /sanctum/csrf-cookie.

Next, the `allowed-origins`. By default, it is set to `*`, which means "any origin". An origin is the protocol, domain and port number of the app sending a request to your Laravel API. So going back to our earlier examples, their origins would be `http://localhost:3000` and `https://www.my-awesome-app.io`. These are the exact values you should use to allow requests from your front-end app:

```
'allowed_origins' => ['http://localhost:3000'],
```

I would recommend moving this to the .env file, and having a separate origin for local and production.

```
/config/cors.php
...
'allowed_origins' => [env('ALLOWED_ORIGINS')],


/.env
...
ALLOWED_ORIGINS=http://localhost:3000
```

The documentation does mention the last part of our cors config, which is that

```
'supports_credentials' => false,
```

Must be changed to:

```
'supports_credentials' => true,
```

Our /config/cors.php file now looks like:

**Modified**

```
/config/cors.php
...
'paths' => [
    'api/*',
    'sanctum/csrf-cookie'
],
'allowed_methods' => ['*'],
'allowed_origins' => [env('ALLOWED_ORIGINS')],
'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],
'allowed_headers' => ['*'],
'exposed_headers' => [],
'max_age' => 0,
'supports_credentials' => true,
```

**Bonus info**, Chrome will not allow a credentialed request to a server that returns the header
`Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`

[Google Chrome: A wildcard '*' cannot be used in the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header when the credentials flag is true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39286997/google-chrome-a-wildcard-cannot-be-used-in-the-access-control-allow-origin)

So you should make sure you set a specific origin in your cors config!

*Finally, you should ensure your application's session cookie domain configuration supports any subdomain of your root domain. You may do this by prefixing the domain with a leading . within your session configuration file:*

This isn't complicated, but seems it can catch people out so thought I'd mention it. Given our examples so far, we'd make the following change to our config/session.php file:

```
'domain' => '.my-awesome-app.io',
```

Locally, `localhost` alone is fine:

```
'domain' => 'localhost',
```

Assuming you've followed the rest of the instructions in the Sanctum documentation (setting `axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;`, adding the middleware etc) your backend configuration is now complete.

**Front end and authentication.**

I love Sanctum and I'm very grateful for the creators; so I say this with respect; the documentation lacks a little depth at this point. Grabbing the csrf-token is very straight forward, and then...

*Once CSRF protection has been initialized, you should make a POST request to the typical Laravel /login route. This /login route may be provided by the laravel/jetstream authentication scaffolding package.
If the login request is successful, you will be authenticated and subsequent requests to your API routes will automatically be authenticated via the session cookie that the Laravel backend issued to your client.*

**It seems they've updated the docs!**
As I write this, I've checked the latest docs and it's now highlighted the fact that you are free to write your own login endpoint. This was always the case, but might have escaped a few people, perhaps given the instructions above ("you should make a POST request to the typical Laravel /login route.") It's also perhaps not clear that you can override default Laravel methods to prevent unwanted side-effects of the default auth setup, like redirecting to the /home page etc.

Writing your own login controller is simple, and I prefer to do so for Sanctum. Here's one you can use:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
  
  public function login(Request $request)
  {
    $request->validate([
      'email' => ['required', 'email'],
      'password' => 'required'
    ]);

    $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');

    if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
      return response()->json(Auth::user(), 200);
    }

    throw ValidationException::withMessages([
      'email' => 'The provided credentails are incorect.'
    ]);

  }
}
```

Feel free to modify this to suit your needs.

How you manage your state (making sure your app remembers you are logged in, for example) on the front-end is also up to you. There are lots of options, however if we're using Sanctum I think we should focus on a simple cookie-based approach. Here's one I use:

1. Login to your app. An auth session is established and your browser saves the cookies provided by your Laravel API.
2. Have your login script return the authenticated user (the one provided above does just that). Save the details of that user to your app state (eg. Vuex).
3. Check your state contains the user any time you need to secure an action against unauthorised users. Redirect to the login page is the auth check fails.

Here's the above in Nuxt.js form using middleware.

```
/middleware/auth-check.js

export default async function ({ store, redirect }) {
  // Check if the user is not already in the store.
  if (store.state.user === null) {
    // Call your Laravel API to get the currently authenticated user.
    // It doesn't matter if the store has been wiped out due to a page
    // refresh- the browser still has the cookies, which will be sent
    // along with this request.
    try {
      let rsp = await user.getAuthenticatedUser()
      // If we get the user from the Laravel API, push it back in to
      // the store and carry on to the page.
      store.commit('SET_AUTH_USER', rsp.data)
    } catch (e) {
      // If our API doesn't return the user for any reason, redirect to
      // the login page.
      return redirect('/login')
    }
  }
  // If not, carry on to the page.
}


/pages/admin.vue

export default {
  middleware: auth-check
}
```

The code above is for example purposes, but it's generally what I use for Vue/Nuxt and Sanctum.

Hope this helps, happy to elaborate further if anyone can benefit.

Comment: This is gold. Much appreciated my friend! One question for you, how might you implement the forgot/reset password with this? Since laravel tries to do it using the built-in methods and tries to send users to the laravel app instead of the spa app through email link. Solving that would take care of all my auth needs with nuxt.

Comment: That would be an interesting exercise; almost every aspect of the framework can be extended or overriden, it's just a matter of routing around to see how things work. Unfortunately I can't provide Laravel specific code examples, I haven't taken that approach myself so far. Would you consider writing your own? A reset is straight forward enough, as the user is logged in- just offer a simple form in the account section, grab a new password, then send it over to your API for validation and handling.

Comment: The "forgot password" feature is a little more involved, but totally doable- there are lots of resources available if you search for "forgotten password in php" or similar. If you're sure you want to dig into the default Laravel methods, I'd recommend an IDE that let's you click in to methods and class names. It makes following the trail of code a lot easier!

Comment: So what you're saying is I'd have to kind of build my own using/extending what laravel already has? I knew that was an option, I just didnt know if that would be best practice to do so since now I have to maintain that

Comment: Others may comment with a different opinion, but I think creating your own methods that suit your specific use case is the way to go. Just like with the login feature- you can write your own, or you can override/disable Laravel’s default behaviour (the redirect). As for best practices, remember the Sanctum docs have been updated to point out the fact that rolling your own login controller is totally an option if the framework defaults don’t work for your situation.

Comment: @NickDawes, Thank you for this great information but, unforetunatly this will not work if the frontend and backend are sperated you will be able to comunicate with api but the login will not work because of CORS  I always got 419 error when try to login.